# Sap Unique Employee number

Tags: sap-erp

We are using an older version of SAP and don't have access to the database itself.

The version is SAP ECC 6.0.

Can anyone tell me where I can find a unique employee Id/ number for an employee?

SAP No is no good as employees can have 2 positions and that would mean 2 different SAP numbers?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not really clear on what is the problem, and what you want to accomplish.

I assume you're speaking about the HCM/HR module.

An employee that belongs to several companies will possess several employeeid's. If an employee occupies two positions in the same company, it will have only one employeeid (field pernr in all infotypes tables).  However, it has two relationship with "S" objects (Job) in OM.

If you have an employee in several companies, you can create a solution. There are a lot of ways to do so (as always with SAP). It depends also on what (sub) module you want to use ? PA  ? OM ?

In the first case, you could use a field of the IT0032 (badge for example), or create a shared infotype, with a GroupId / UniqId that is filled during infotype creation.

In the second case, you could use the "CP" object (central Person) in OM to get a relationship with all the P objects (person / employeeId) of the employee.

It really depends on the HR Processes and the current customization of your SAP system.

Comment: Thanks Patry.  I think the pernr in the infotype tables is what we are looking for.  The employees are in the same company but may have more than one position.  Cheers for your help

Answer (score 1):

SAP HCM has the transaction **PA20** which display personnel data. Actually, the right name of transaction is: **Display HR Master Data**.

1. Execute PA20.
2. Look up the field you want.
3. Hit F1 over there.
4. Hit over hammer icon.
5. Look up field name and table name.

OR

to run SE16, accessing the table: **PA0105** and column name: **PERNR** - Personnel number.